# how to create undefined number of threads and use WaitForMultipleObjects() in c on windows

Tags: c, windows, multithreading, winsock, waitformultipleobjects

PS: I am very new to threads.

I have a problem where i need to wait for connection requests(completely arbitrary number of times) from clients, accept a connection on a socket, create a worker thread after connection. The created thread then creates a char array, works on it and needs to pass it to  the parent process.

I have been able to create the threads in a while loop like

```
while ((new_socket = accept(srv_sock, (struct sockaddr *)&client, &c)) != INVALID_SOCKET)
{
    puts("\nConnection accepted");
    _beginthreadex(0, 0, handle_client, &new_socket, 0, 0);

}
```

I have seen that `pthread_join()` can be used to pass data from thread to parent process(in unix). My question is, how can I integrate it into a loop in the main process.
I expect the following approach will result in a situation where no more than one connection can be established between client and server at a time,which is not desired.

```
 while ((new_socket = accept(srv_sock, (struct sockaddr *)&client, &c)) != INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        puts("\nConnection accepted");
        _beginthreadex(0, 0, handle_client, &new_socket, 0, 0);
        pthread_join(thread_id,&my_array);

    }
```

EDIT: I would be happy to know if what I want is impossible or if there are alternatives to `pthread_join().` or its windows equivalent.

EDIT: I know that `pthread_join()` is for Unix and have read that `WaitForMultipleObjects()` is its equivalent for windows. In any case I still haven't been able to figure out a solution.

Comment: The 'Windows' way of doing this would be, I guess, to wait on an IOCP completion port for both client connection accepts, (overlapped AcceptEx), and for queued messages from the client threads, (PostQueuedCompletionStatus).  Alternatively, run the Accept() loop in a different thread and queue everything to your 'main thread', (or whatever it is that is going to manage it all ), on a producer-consumer queue, (maybe PostMessage,GetMessage).

Comment: TBH, 'join()' is a bit of a PITA in all cases, and you should try to avoid it, if you can.  If you can design so as to not have to wait for threads to finish, you will have a much easier time of multithreaded programming and avoid a lot of pain.  Same goes for any design that relies on counting the number of threads - design so it doesn't matter, and avoid the bother.

Answer (score 0):

> I have seen that pthread_join() can be used to pass data from thread to parent process.

That is not entirely correct. You can pass a pointer when you **exit** a thread, and collect that pointer using pthread_join. You have to implement all the logic yourself. The API does not know (or care) what the pointer is. Threads don't have parents and children, they are siblings.

Example for a creator and a reaper:

- global

  ```
  struct VarLengthArray {
      size_t count;
      MyElem data[1];
  };
  ```
- exiting thread:

  ```
  // allocate the result
  size_t count = ...;
  VarLengthArray *retval = malloc(
      sizeof(VarLengthArray) +
      sizeof(MyElem) * (count > 0 ? count - 1 : 0)
  );

  // fill the result
  retval->count = count;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < retval->count; ++i) {
      retval->data[i] = ...;
  }
  pthread_exit(retval);
  ```
- collecting thread:

  ```
  // collect the result
  void *retval_;
  if (pthread_join(thread_one_id, &retval_) != 0) {
      // handle error
  }
  VarLengthArray *retval = retval_;

  // use the result
  for (size_t i = 0; i < retval->count; ++i) {
      printf("retval->[%u] = %s\n", (unsigned) i, retval->data[i].string_value);
  }

  // deallocate the result
  free(retval);
  ```

---

A full example using a **condition variable** and multiple creators:

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

typedef struct Datum {
    struct Datum *next;
    char some_data[32];
} Datum;

typedef struct SharedData {
    pthread_mutex_t mutex;
    pthread_cond_t cond_empty;
    unsigned seed;
    Datum *head, *tail;
    unsigned children_alive;
} SharedData;

static void *thread_logic(void *argv_);

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    unsigned thread_count = 2;
    if (argc > 1) {
        if (sscanf(argv[1], " %u ", &thread_count) != 1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s [thread_count]\n", argv[0]);
            return 1;
        }
    }

    // initialize shared data
    SharedData shared_data;
    pthread_mutex_init(&shared_data.mutex, NULL);
    pthread_cond_init(&shared_data.cond_empty, NULL);
    shared_data.seed = time(NULL);
    shared_data.head = NULL;
    shared_data.tail = NULL;
    shared_data.children_alive = 0;

    // start threads detached, so you don't have to call pthread_join
    pthread_t *child_ids = malloc(sizeof(pthread_t) * thread_count);
    pthread_attr_t attr;
    pthread_attr_init(&attr);
    pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED);

    // start the threads
    pthread_mutex_lock(&shared_data.mutex);
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < thread_count; ++i) {
        if (pthread_create(&child_ids[i], &attr, thread_logic, &shared_data) != 0) {
            perror("pthread_create");
        } else {
            ++shared_data.children_alive;
        }
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&shared_data.mutex);

    pthread_attr_destroy(&attr);

    // loop until all threads are dead
    while (shared_data.children_alive > 0) {
        // a condition variable: wait until there is data you can read
        pthread_mutex_lock(&shared_data.mutex);
        while (shared_data.head == NULL) {
            pthread_cond_wait(&shared_data.cond_empty, &shared_data.mutex);
        }

        // collect a first datum
        Datum *datum = shared_data.head;
        if (datum->next != NULL) {
            shared_data.head = datum->next;
        } else {
            shared_data.head = shared_data.tail = NULL;
        }

        pthread_mutex_unlock(&shared_data.mutex);

        // handle the data (outside of the mutex lock)
        printf("Got data: %s\n", datum->some_data);
        free(datum);
    }

    return 0;
}

static void *thread_logic(void *shared_data_) {
    SharedData *shared_data = shared_data_;
    while (1) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&shared_data->mutex);

        // create some data
        useconds_t timeout = (
            (((float) (unsigned) rand_r(&shared_data->seed)) / UINT_MAX) *
            1000000
        );
        Datum *datum = malloc(sizeof(Datum));
        datum->next = NULL;
        if (timeout < 1000000 / 25) {
            --shared_data->children_alive;
            snprintf(datum->some_data, sizeof(datum->some_data), "I'm done\n");
        } else {
            snprintf(
                datum->some_data, sizeof(datum->some_data),
                "Sleeping for %uus\n", timeout
            );
        }

        // append the datum
        if (shared_data->head) {
            shared_data->tail->next = datum;
        } else {
            shared_data->head = datum;
            pthread_cond_signal(&shared_data->cond_empty);
        }
        shared_data->tail = datum;

        pthread_mutex_unlock(&shared_data->mutex);

        // most likely it takes some time to create the data
        // do lengthly tasks outside of the mutex lock
        if (timeout < 1000000 / 25) {
            return NULL;
        } else {
            usleep(timeout);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how to pthread_join() in loop? and I also dont know how many threads were created.

Comment: @George, I'll update on my answer, but it will take a few minutes. I'll ping you when I'm done. :)

Comment: I think the way i asked my question was misleading. Sorry. I am looking for a windows solution and there is no way for me to know in advance the number of threads that will be created.